# How to separate the elements from Google vicinity api?

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps-api-3

In my iOS application i want to split the words from google API vicinity, The api result shows as follows,

```
 "vicinity" : "24/49,TV Swamy Road East,, TV Swamy Street, RS Puram, Coimbatore"
 "vicinity" : "48, T.V. Swamy Road West, T.V. Swamy Road (West), Near Tasmac, R.S. Puram, Coimbatore"
 "vicinity" : "Diwan Bhadur Road, RS Puram, Coimbatore"
 "vicinity" : "Avinashi Road, P.S.G. College Stop, Avinashi Road, Near P.S.G. Optical Centre, Peelamedu, Coimbatore"
```

Here the code which I try to use to trim

```
 __block NSString *lastWord = nil;

[str enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [str length]) options:NSStringEnumerationByWords | NSStringEnumerationReverse usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange subrange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
    lastWord = substring;
    *stop = YES;
}];
```

But the results are as follows

```
 Coimbatore
 Coimbatore
 Coimbatore
 Coimbatore
```

I want to show only the trimmed details like follows from the above result

```
 "TV Swamy Street, RS Puram, Coimbatore"
 "R.S. Puram, Coimbatore"
 "RS Puram, Coimbatore"
 "Peelamedu, Coimbatore"
```

How to trim the details like the above?

Comment: What is your logic to clip the vicinity string? If you want only the last two components it is rather easy.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what is your logic for cropping the strings. If you want only last two components you can do it this way

```
NSArray *results = @[@{@"vicinity" : @"24/49,TV Swamy Road East,, TV Swamy Street, RS Puram, Coimbatore"},
  @{@"vicinity" : @"48, T.V. Swamy Road West, T.V. Swamy Road (West), Near Tasmac, R.S. Puram, Coimbatore"},
  @{@"vicinity" : @"Diwan Bhadur Road, RS Puram, Coimbatore"},
  @{@"vicinity" : @"Avinashi Road, P.S.G. College Stop, Avinashi Road, Near P.S.G. Optical Centre, Peelamedu, Coimbatore"}];

    NSMutableArray *formattedResults = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSDictionary *dict in results) {
        NSString *vicinity = dict[@"vicinity"];

        NSArray *components = [vicinity componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
        NSUInteger length = 2;
        if ([components count]<length) {
            break;
        }
        NSRange range = NSMakeRange([components count]-length, length);
        NSArray *croppedComponents = [components subarrayWithRange:range];

        NSString *croppedVicinity = [croppedComponents componentsJoinedByString:@","];

        if (croppedVicinity) {
            [formattedResults addObject:croppedVicinity];
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"%@",formattedResults);
```